# Scroll through column from top to bottom and replace 0's with value from cell above

Tags: excel, vba

I have to scroll through a column (actually two, but if I can get one going I can manage) from top to bottom and replace the `0`'s or blanks with cell value above it. This is what I have so far (it doesn't work):

```
Sub ReplaceZeros()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                                          
For i = lr To 2 Step 7000                                                             
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = 0 Then Cells(i, "A").Replace_
    What: 0, Replacement:= "cell(i-1,"A").value,_
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Next i


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `column above it` mean?

Comment: oh i meant cell value above. fixed

Comment: you're right, my coworker just taught me this trick. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close:

```
Sub ReplaceZeros()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = 0 Then .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value
    Next i
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note: The loop you had started at the bottom and went up, this would be fine but if you had two '0' in a row the second would remain zero, plus the `step 7000` made the loop skip 7000 rows at a time.

Then if all you want is the value above using `Cells(i-1,"A").value` will return the value of the cells directly above.

Comment: any advice on how i can implement this to many columns at once?

Comment: @ichoi, that my friend is a new question.  But, it would require another loop that goes from 1 to the extents of your columns and you would replace all the "A" in your cell reference with the variable from the loop.  Try that and if you get stuck post a new question.