# Delete rows based on not containing names

Tags: vba, if-statement

```
Sub Chadsrebate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).Value <>"A","B","C","D" then 
entirerow.delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: So... what's the question? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: Go look at your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656858/scroll-through-column-from-top-to-bottom-and-replace-0s-with-value-from-cell-ab), You will need to do almost the exact same thing with a loop, the only difference is the column through which you are looping and the if statement.  Use that information and look into IF..AND statements then come back.

Comment: So I have a data pull that has total customer names. I need to delete all rows but the rows containing said A,B,C,D, etc. I get an error after the then.

Comment: Yeah I considered the loop, but if I do that and a <> the names that I need but not in the first loop will all be deleted.

Comment: you need to loop on  column B not column A Change the `"A"` to "B"` and your if statement should be `If .Cells(i,"B").value <> "A" and .Cells(i,"B") <> "B" And ...` continue till you get through all the different strings to test. Your delete statement would be rows(i).entirerows.delete.  One last note you need to tod the for loop backwards `for i = lr to 2 step -1`

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To -1
        If .Cells(i, "b").Value <> "Adboom Group, Inc (LNI)" And .Cells(i, "b").Value <> "Bio Nutraceuticals" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub`

Comment: I think that'w what you mean and I get an error message of "next without for" if i delete next I get "end with without with" and if i delete the with/with end i get an error in the: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).`   .... rows portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*one of the ways how you can achieve this:*

if you want to delete all rows which are contain names:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Chadsrebate()
    Dim i&, z&
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        With Sheets("Sheet2")
            i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For z = i To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*A*" _
                    Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*F*" _
                        Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*Z*" _
                            Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*Q*" Then
                    .Rows(z).Delete
                End If
            Next z
            z = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    MsgBox i - z & " Rows has been deleted!"
End Sub
```

if you want to delete all rows which are NOT contain names:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Chadsrebate()
    Dim i&, z&
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        With Sheets("Sheet2")
            i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For z = i To 2 Step -1
                If Not (.Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*A*" _
                    Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*F*" _
                        Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*Z*" _
                            Or .Cells(z, "B").Value2 Like "*Q*") Then
                    .Rows(z).Delete
                End If
            Next z
            z = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    MsgBox i - z & " Rows has been deleted!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code deletes values A,F,Z and Q. I am trying to delete all other values but A,F,Z and Q. I tried replacing "like" with <>, but this does not work, it simply deletes everything.