# Copy last cell value in a in blank cell just below the group of cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Column A
2
5
7
(It is blank cell, but I want to copy 7 that is last value of this group cell)
5
1
2
5
(It is blank cell, but I want to copy 5 that is last value of this group cell)
2
5
(It is blank cell, but I want to copy 5 that is last value of this group cell)
```

And so on, there are many group cells, but I want to copy last value of group cell in a blank cell.

I also want to change the the text color of that cell which is copied .

Please suggest me effective Macro.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656858/scroll-through-column-from-top-to-bottom-and-replace-0s-with-value-from-cell-ab/33656961#33656961

Comment: Your edit added a condition after you got an answer to your original question.  You should mark the below as correct and pose an new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To fill-down **one additional cell**, use this version:

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next

    Cells(N + 1, "A").FillDown
End Sub
```

***BEFORE:***

[image]

***AFTER:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I change color of that cell. For eg. 'change formatting to your liking:
        formulaCell.Font.Bold = True
        formulaCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Comment: I have also implemented change text color successfully. But I found one problem in this macro, it do not copy the last group cell value of the column. I can do manually but if you can complete this macro, then it is really very good solution. Please help.

Comment: @RanjeetRai  See my **EDIT#1**